# Swift · Dismissing Modal ViewController and reload tableview afterwards

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, modalviewcontroller, xcode11.4

this is my first iOS App.
I’m using a Modal ViewlController to save new list entries.
Unfortunately I can't manage to update the tableView with the new entry afterwards.
[Here is a screen cast o the current state of the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9wzJ.gif)

I tried other solutions on stack overflow, but somehow my app always crashes after pressing the *Load New Film Button*. I recognised, that most user call there Modal ViewController within the code, that doesn't worked for me either.

So I did it in the storyboard: 
[screencast Modal ViewController via segue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDOFt.gif)

Could you help me with reloading the tableView, please?

Here is my code:

**This is the main ViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class LoadedFilmsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var filmRolls: Results<FilmRoll>?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: K.cellNibNameLoaded, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: K.CellIdentifier.CellFilmRoll)
        loadFilmRolls()
    }        

    //MARK: - TableView Datasource Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return filmRolls?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let df = DateFormatter()
        df.dateFormat = "d. MMMM yyyy"
        let dateAsString = df.string(from: filmRolls?[indexPath.row].dateLoaded ?? Date())

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.CellIdentifier.CellFilmRoll, for: indexPath) as! LoadedFilmCell
        cell.labelFilmStock.text = filmRolls?[indexPath.row].filmStock ?? "No film roll added yet."
        cell.labelCamera.text = filmRolls?[indexPath.row].camera ?? "No film roll added yet."
        cell.labelDateLoaded.text = dateAsString
        return cell
    }


    //MARK: - Add new Film Rolls
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    }

    func loadFilmRolls() {
        filmRolls = realm.objects(FilmRoll.self)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }        
}
```

**This it the Modal View:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class AddNewRollViewController: UIViewController {

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var filmRolls: Results<FilmRoll>?


    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldFilmStock: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldCamera: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFieldFilmStock.placeholder = "Kodak Color Plus 200"
        textFieldCamera.placeholder = "Canon AE-1"
    }

    @IBAction func addNewFilmRollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let newFilmRoll = FilmRoll()
        newFilmRoll.filmStock = textFieldFilmStock.text!
        newFilmRoll.camera = textFieldCamera.text!
        newFilmRoll.dateLoaded = Date()

        do {
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newFilmRoll)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error saving FilmRoll \(error)")
        }

        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you dismiss the modal can you add code in the ccompletion, stick the loadFilmRolls func in and it should refresh it.

```
  override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool,
                         completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    loadFilmRolls()
}
```

I've not tested it but it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

In `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` you can provide a completion block that will be executed after the view is dismissed

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    if let viewController = presentingViewController as? LoadedFilmsTableViewController {
        viewController.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.
Unfortunately I get the following error:

 _Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit_



I tried to fix it by adding self:

`dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            if let viewController = self.presentingViewController as? LoadedFilmsTableViewController {
                viewController.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        })`

in the result nothing happened after dismissing the view – still no reload.
Any idea?